# Using Random to call a dictionary from a different class

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making a small game and I'm trying to have the EncounterM class get a random Monster and Dmg from the monster class dictionary. (New at Python)

```
 class Monster:

        monster_health = {'goblin': 15, 'giant': 50}
        monster_damage = {'goblin': 3, 'giant': 1}




 class EncounterM(Monster): 
        import random 



 # I tried using random.choice(monster_health.keys())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll ignore the not-working-at-all object constructions to focus on your question. Read more about object, instances, classes and post another question.
(Edit: I couldn't resist to change it a little to make it a little more object-like, but I won't go further)

With Python 3, `keys()` do not return a list anymore. You have to cast to `list` explicitly for it to work

```
import random

class Monster:
   health = {'goblin': 15, 'giant': 50}
   damage = {'goblin': 3, 'giant': 1}

print(random.choice(list(Monster.health.keys())))
```

output:

```
giant
(or goblin)
```